# Testing the validity of entity entry

Tags: dialogflow-es

The user is required to enter an ID number which populates a parameter and will then be used to look up a database. All IDs are 11 digits long and start with a 1 and a 0. How can I test the number entered by the user to ensure it meets these requirements and then reprompt if their entry is invalid?

The parameter is currenty a number type entity. Within the intent, it is a required parameter, the intent itself is first triggered by the user entering "MBTN" which is the name of the ID number. This number will be used to look up associated value in a database. The purpose of checking the validity before looking up the database is to reduce the number of wasted calls to the database. 
I feel like this will require some code to put in place but am unsure of the best way to approach this in Dialogflow. Has anyone done anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a fulfillment webhook to validate the ID. Please go through documentation on how to set it up:
[Dialogflow Fulfillment using Webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/tutorials/build-an-agent/create-fulfillment-using-webhook)